# How are we able to locally linearize a non-linear transform with the Jacobian matrix?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, jacobian

After watching this video, [The Jacobian Matrix](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/jacobian/v/the-jacobian-matrix), I animated what I interpreted from the video

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbL8G.jpg

While animating, I got the following doubt, when we look at $(1, 1)$, in the un-zoomed version, it's not fixed. I actually had to move the camera frame to be centered around $(1,1)$ in the zoomed in version. Now a linear transform has its origin (local $(x_0, y_0)$) fixed, I mean, $(1,1)$ should be mapped to itself if it were a linear transform, right?
If the local origin is not fixed, then how do we use the Jacobian matrix to approximate the non linear transform as a linear transform locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true that the point itself is moved. But it is how *neighbouring points* are moved in *relation to one another* that the Jacobian records. So in the zoomed-in version, we are *following* $(1, 1)$ as it moves to $f(1, 1)$. We are keeping that point fixed in the middle of our screen, and watching how the points *around* $(1, 1)$ move during the same transformation. And it turns out that if we zoom in far enough, the points around $(1, 1)$ move in a fashion that looks almost linear.

More formally, if we have our function $f$, our point of interest $p$, and the Jacobian $J(p)$ at that point, then
$$
f(p+v)\approx f(p) + J(p)v
$$
for small vectors $v$ (where $\approx$ has a formally defined meaning). This is completely analoguous to how the regular derivative of a function works:
$$
g(x + t) \approx g(x) + g'(x) t
$$
for small numbers $t$ (or maybe you're more used to $g'(x)\approx \frac{g(x + t) - g(x)}{t}$, but that's the same thing). In fact, the derivative is simply the $1\times 1$ special case of the Jacobian.

Comment: So we zoom in, and find a linear problem and so we assemble a matrix to represent the transform. And finally add the missing constant to every point in the neighborhood. Is that it?

Comment: So the approximation is not good enough without the addition of that common factor.

Comment: @Aravindh Yes, basically. If we want to guess the value of $f(1.0001,0.9999)$, then our first (zeroth, really) approximation, given by continuity, is that it will be close to $f(1,1)$, so that's bound to be a decent approximation. The next approximation, given by differentiability, is that the value is close to $f(1,1)+J[0.0001,-0.0001]^T$. In fact, the function $v\mapsto f(1,1)+Jv$ is linear (in the sense of analysis, not linear algebra), and it is the linear function that best approximates $f$ around $(1,1)$.